# Nginx $http_upgrade is always empty

Tags: nginx, websocket, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a websocket program where I use nginx as a router. The problem is that websocket needs the Upgrade header to work properly. I'm sure my nginx config is correct and my program is working properly. (I tested with localhost). Details and proof? I leave it below. I hope a solution is found

Related config;

```
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_x_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header UpgradeTest $http_upgrade+"_test"; #for be sure
proxy_set_header UpgradeXTest $http_x_upgrade+"_test"; #for be sure
proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade"; #this is ok
```

Request;

```
curl -v 'https://mywebsocketserver.example/abc' -H 'Upgrade: websocket' -H 'Connection: Upgrade' -H "TestHeader: IAmHere"
```

Response (header) (go-map);

```
map[
         Testheader: IAmHere
         Accept: */*
         Accept-Encoding: gzip
         Cdn-Loop: cloudflare
         Cf-Connecting-Ip: <myip>
         Cf-Ray: 65a1b1ff3a30fd66-ATH
         Cf-Request-Id: 0a78ef738d0000fd66e76a8000000
         Cf-Visitor: {"scheme":"https"}
         Connection: Upgrade
         Demote-Host: <myip>
         Upgradetest: +"_test"
         Upgradextest: +"_test"
         User-Agent: curl/7.76.0
         X-Forwarded-Proto: https
         X-Real-Ip: <myip>
]
```

So, where is my Upgrade [$http_upgrade] header :)

Comment: I hacked my library and replaced Upgrade header with X-Upgrade. Now my app is working but i haven't found solution yet